# how to define permission for custom model

Tags: liferay-6

**How to define permission for custom model like Employee.**
I am having one portlet where I can perform CURD operation on Employee object(custom model).
Using this link :
 [Permission for custom model](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Permissioning+in+Plugin+Environment)
In above post they are using ext-plugin. Is it possible any other way?

Comment: AS I am also new to liferay but I guess this link will give you some idea http://liferaysatish.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-permissions-system-works-in-liferay.html